# I have more than 100000 files, How to read those files using the Hashmap in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, hashmap, inputstream

I am working on android expansion files, during the process I am using the Hashmap functions to store the files and read. While reading the files, only 21900 files can be read but I actually have more than 100000 files. The remaining files can not be read from the OBB file. How to read the whole files?

```
public InputStream getInputStream(String assetPath) throws IOException {
    ZipEntryRO entry = mHashMap.get(assetPath);
    if (mHashMap.containsKey(assetPath) ) {
        if (entry.isUncompressed()) {
            return entry.getAssetFileDescriptor().createInputStream();
        } else {
            ZipFile zf = mZipFiles.get(entry.getZipFile());
            /** read compressed files **/
            if (null == zf) {
                zf = new ZipFile(entry.getZipFile(), ZipFile.OPEN_READ);
                mZipFiles.put(entry.getZipFile(), zf);
            }
            ZipEntry zi = zf.getEntry(assetPath);
            if (null != zi)
                return zf.getInputStream(zi);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean read using a hashmap?  The question doesn't make sense. You say only 21K files can be read-  what happens after that?  Do you crash?  If so with what error?  You need a lot more detail.

Comment: Also-  I can't think of a single reason anyone would ever need to read 100K files in a row.  You're almost certainly doing something wrong, and quite possibly impossible depending on filesize and how you're storing the data in RAM.

Comment: Well, don't store all 100000 files in memory, when in reality you need only one at a time. Problem solved!

Comment: Their is no crash, it returns null value even when the file is present.

Comment: I attached my code above

Comment: I have 100k audio and image files, I am able to play and view some files using the above code remaining I am getting it as null

Comment: If I understand your question right. You want to read whole 100k files and save the inputstream into hashmap. I can say that's impossible.

Comment: You appear to have put a large number of `ZipEntry` objects into your hashmap keyed by their pathname, but to read them you have to reopen the `ZipFile` they came from and re-get the `ZipEntry` and get an input stream from that. It is difficult to see the point. You would be better off just storing the `assetPath` and the containing filename in the Hashmap and losing the stored `ZipEntry` altogether. It isn't doing you any good and it is wasting memory on a pretty colossal scale. You are also creating *new* `ZipFiles` and putting empty entries into them, which seems even more pointless.

Comment: Please include more of your code; where is `mHashMap` defined, and where is it populated? If this method is the only place `mHashMap` is populated `mHashMap.containsKey()` will always return false and the method will return `null`.

Comment: You would also do well to step back and confirm this is really what you need. It's like you're trying to solve some *other* problem with this map-of-files solution. Consider asking a question about how to better address *that* problem, instead.